# msvc equivalent to __attribute__((unused)) for functions, arguments and local variables

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

### Problem

In the Cython implementation a common macro is used to suppress unused warnings.

```cpp
# define CYTHON_UNUSED __attribute__ ((__unused__))
```

It is used to suppress warnings about unused functions:

```cpp
CYTHON_UNUSED int func(int arg)
```

unused arguments:

```cpp
int func(CYTHON_UNUSED int arg)
```

and unused local variables:

```cpp
CYTHON_UNUSED int var;
```

Since `__attribute__ ((__unused__))` does not exist for msvc I tried to come up with a solution for msvc. The solution I came up with was to use `__pragma(warning(suppress: 4100 4101 4505))` as an equivalent to suppress the warnings. However this might suppress multiple warnings. The following code:

```
CYTHON_UNUSED int func(int arg1, int arg2) {
    int var;
    return 0;
}
```

will not only suppress the warning about the unused function, but the two warnings about the arguments and the warning about the variable as well.

### My current solution

#### function warnings

For function warnings `__pragma(warning(suppress: 4505))` can be used, which will work unless someone write something like the following:

```cpp
static CYTHON_UNUSED  int func() { return 0; }
static int func2() { return 0; }
```

Which would still ignore both warnings.

#### argument and variable warnings

For both variable and argument warnings I did not find a better solution than casting to void:

```cpp
int var;
(void)var;
```

### Question

Is there a different way to achieve this using MSVC?
The solution has the following requirements:

- has to work both in C and C++
- should only suppress a single warning
- if there are multiple ways to achieve this it is preferred to have as few changes to the current syntax as possible.

Comment: How about `[[maybe_unused]]` (not tested with MSVC) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused  ?

Comment: In MSVC, `__pragma(warning)` applies to the current *and* the next line. That's why you don't see the warning for `func2`.

Comment: @RichardCritten [Looks like it works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/attributes?view=msvc-160), if your version of MSVC is new enough.

Comment: @PaulSanders How does it manage in terms of the OP's: *has to work both in C and C++*?

Comment: @AdrianMole Good point.  I tested it, and it doesn't work in C, only in C++.

Comment: @RichardCritten This only works for C++17, so it can only be a partial solution. We also use the macro on static functions. However [[maybe_unused]] on msvc does not implement the warning suppression for this case: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/c-attribute-maybe-unused-is-ignored-for-static-fun/244236

Comment: @rustyx Yes I know (so you can write the pragma in the line above). In this specific case thats not problematic, since there is no similar case in the Cython code base. However we did run into parsing errors of msvc when using the macro with the warning pragma on msvc, that I could not really resolve.

Comment: You never mentioned any parsing errors in the question. Anyway, there is no other way, especially given your requirements.

Comment: Yes the question here is not really on the parsing error, but on the general way to do this in msvc. After I know this I can still try to work around the parsing error.